# How to retrieve ID from MYSQL table after Insert in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

All I am trying to do is retrieve the contact_id after inserting a row into the database

```
try {
  // Connect and create the PDO object
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
  $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

    // Prepare Form Contents
    // Split full name to First and Last Name
    $both = $_POST['contact_name']; // Get the full name
    $both = str_replace('.', '. ', $both); // Give it a new variable name
    $both = preg_replace('/[^ ]+\./', '', $both); // Strip Spaces
    $both = trim(str_replace('  ', ' ', $both));
    list($fname, $lname) = explode(" ", $both, 2); // Get the two variables
    // Set values for contact
    $email      = $_POST['contact_email'];
    $tel        = $_POST['contact_tel'];
    $jtitle     = $_POST['contact_jtitle'];
    // Get the Date
    $today = date("Y-m-d"); 

    // Define an insert query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `telephone`, `job_title`, `reg_date`)
                VALUES
            ('$fname','$lname','$email','$tel','$jtitle','$today')";
            $count = $conn->exec($sql);
    // Get the Contact ID        
        $foo = "SELECT `contact_id` FROM `contacts` WHERE `email` = ' .$email. '";
            $cid = $conn->exec($foo);

            $conn = null;        // Disconnect
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The problem is that $cid always returns as 0

(I appreciate I am a complete novice and any pointers to making the code better in general is appreciated)

Comment: You're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Learn about that and fix the problem before you work on any other problems with the code. Then RTLM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php  you're using `->exec()` incorrectly. And your select has syntax errors anyways, so it'll fail regardless of how you execute it.

Comment: If column 'contact_id' is a primary key, then check for last inserted id (with PDO) instead of using select-statement to figure out id. Also check for examples that uses PDO. You will learn a lot by that.

Answer (score 1):

Last insert id method should do it :-

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that contact_id is your primary key, you can use  PDO::lastInsertId(), so in your case:

```
$cid = $conn->lastInsertId();
```